# How do I enable automatic graphics switching in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, graphics-card, macbook-pro

Google Chrome doesn't switch my MacBook Pro's active GPU to the discrete graphics card to render WebGL. I want Chrome to do what graphics-heavy apps such as Final Cut Pro do—switching from integrated to high performance graphics—when there's a tab open that has WebGL in it. Hardware acceleration is on in settings, but it never uses the discrete graphics card. How do I enable automatic graphics switching in Google Chrome?

Comment: Take a look at this Super User [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1324995/how-to-change-between-integrated-and-discrete-graphics-in-windows-7)